# Logitech Wave keyboard media control buttons control iTunes?

Tags: drivers, itunes, logitech-keyboard

Before I used to be able to control iTunes with Logitech wave (keyboard)'s media control buttons (play/pause, previous, next, etc)

After reinstalling Windows on my computer, the keys no longer work. I have Logitech Setpoint installed. I don't believe I had any other programs during my previous installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution after searching Google:

- You need to open a text editor (like Notepad) as an administrator.
- Open the SetPoint players.ini file (`C:\Program Files\Logitech\SetPointP\players.ini`)
- Edit the line under the [Players] section to match the line bellow (bold is the wndClass which is to be changed)

  ```
  iTunes=wac,iTunes.exe,ITWindow,xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,0,1,iTunes
  ```
- Save the file
- Restart the SetPoint and hopefully play/pause, next and previous buttons should work (at least they work for me)